# How can I get a count of a model from another model in Django?

Tags: python, django

I need to get the count of "Movies" (Peliculas) directed by a director. Movie and Director are different classes. Thanks to one stackoverflow user I was able to do this from a template but i thought it could be different when we talk about two model classes.

I want to create a function in Director that tells me how many movies he has done but I don't know how to call "Peliculas" from "Director"

```
class Director(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    fecha_defuncion = models.DateField(
        'Fallecido',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    foto = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/directores/',
        default='images/directores/sin_foto.jpg'
    )

    def get_num_peliculas(self):
        n_peliculas = Pelicula.object.all().count #NOT WORKING
        return n_peliculas

class Pelicula(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )
    url_trailer = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )
    fecha = models.DateField()
    notas_posibles = (
        (1, 1),
        (2, 2),
        (3, 3),
        (4, 4),
        (5, 5)
    )
    nota = models.IntegerField(
        default=3,
        choices=notas_posibles
    )
    sinopsis = models.TextField(
        max_length=400,
        default="Sin sinopsis"
    )
    caratula = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/peliculas/caratulas',
        default='images/peliculas/caratulas/sin_caratula.jpg'
    )
    imagen_promocional = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/peliculas/imagenes_promocionales',
        default='images/peliculas/imagenes_promocionales/sin_imagen.jpg'
    )
    genero = models.ManyToManyField(
        Genero,
        blank=True,
        related_name='genero'
    )
    director = models.ForeignKey(
        Director,
        on_delete=models.SET('Sin Director')
    )
    actores = models.ManyToManyField(
        Actor,
        blank=True
    )
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Including irrelevant code in your snippet does not help answer the question. You only care about the foreign keys.

Comment: Also, I have seen you have asked the same question today twice. You shouldn't do this. If you would like the person that answered your question to clear something out for you, you should leave a comment. If you are not happy with the answer, don't accept it. But what you should not do is create duplicate questions. Moderation processes in SO discourage and penalise this sort of behaviour.

Comment: The answer to your question is not only well documented, but also exactly the same as the answer to your previous question: you just have to use the reverse relation.

Comment: Thanks for the first advise. ill be more careful next time.

Comment: About the second one I can tell you that it is the same solution but not the same problem. Maybe it is easy for someone who knows django but not for someone who just started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the relation in reverse, with `pelicula_set`, like:

```
class Director(models.Model):

    # ...

    def get_num_peliculas(self):
        return self.pelicula_set.count()
```

In case you specified a `related_name=...` in the `ForeignKey` to the director, then that is the name of the relation in reverse.

Alternatively, you can `.filter(..)` the queryset, which is basically what happens with such reverse relation:

```
class Director(models.Model):

    # ...

    def get_num_peliculas(self):
        return Pelicula.objects.filter(director=self).count()
```